# AngularJS - Events get removed on month change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

### Issue

---

I have managed to get my events to load up in the `fullCalendar` using AngularJS. The issue arises when I change the month view and all the events disappear.

### Code

---

Here is the code I use to change the month view:

```
//BC - SETS THE MONTH ON THE CALENDAR.
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', MyDateString);
```

Here is the code I use to add events to my calendar (*This is done in the page load function of the controller page*):

```
    var holidays = [];

    $scope.eventSources = [{
        events: [],
        color: '#ffd47f',     // an Event Source Option!
        textColor: '#3c4756' // an Event Source Option!
    }];


    $http.get("http://localhost/AceTracker.svc/GetAllEventsByUser?user_id=1")
.success(function (data) {

    for (var key in data.GetAllEventsByUserResult) {
        if (data.GetAllEventsByUserResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            holidays.push(data.GetAllEventsByUserResult[key])
        }
    }

    holidays.forEach(function (hol) {    //forEach loop through the holidays array data

        $scope.eventSources[0].events.push({ //Push a new object to our eventSOurces array
            end: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_END),
            start: $filter('dateFilter')(hol.HOLIDAY_START),
            title: hol.HOLIDAY_TITLE //Set up fields on new object
        });

    });
});
```

### Conclusion

---

How can I get the events to stay in the calendar?

Comment: You should try angular version of [fullcalendar](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Fullcalendar-Walk-through-with-AngularJS)

Comment: @PankajParkar I am using this?